# MethodBase.IsConstructor does not work as specified with a static constructor

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constructor, static-constructor

Just a simple observation. The [property `MethodBase.IsConstructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isconstructor.aspx) does not work with `static` constructors, and the documentation does not mention this fact (quote: "**true** if this method is a constructor represented by a `ConstructorInfo` object").

Sample:

```
static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(Test).GetConstructor(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { }, null);
    Console.WriteLine(ci is ConstructorInfo); // silly; writes True
    Console.WriteLine(ci.IsConstructor);      // ??     writes False
  }
}

static class Test
{
  static Test()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("I am your static constructor");
  }
}
```

Question: Why? Bug or incomplete specification?

Comment: static constructor is not constructor of object. It is terminology fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Static constructor" is really just C# terminology. In .NET itself, there's a *type initializer* (as per [`Type.TypeInitializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.typeinitializer.aspx)). A type can have a type initializer without having a static constructor declared in C# - e.g. for static variable initialization.

Having a static constructor in the source C# has two effects:

- It removes the [`beforefieldinit`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) flag from the type, potentially changing timing
- It adds the code into the type initializer

So while it's represented by a `ConstructorInfo`, I'm not particularly surprised that `IsConstructor` returns false, in that it's not a constructor in CLR terminology. It's a non-constructor represented by a `ConstructorInfo` object :) It would certainly be clearer if the documentation were reworded to "if this method is an instance constructor" - and also if `GetConstructor` didn't return it (as that's pretty inconsistent, IMO).

Addmittedly the docs for `GetConstructor` do state:

> To get the class initializer (.cctor) using this method overload, you must specify `BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic`. You can also get the class initializer using the `TypeInitializer` property.

... so they're not calling it a constructor there.

Comment: The terminology is confusing then. The property `TypeInitializer` has type ... `ConstructorInfo`, so there is a huge possibility that someone, like me, might think that a "type initializer" was a "constructor". And can you guess what `typeof(Test).TypeInitializer.MemberType` returns? It looks like an alternative to `someMethod.IsConstructor` could be `someMethod.MemberType == MemberTypes.Constructor`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It's definitely confusing, I agree - and the fact that it's returned by `GetConstructor` really doesn't help. Still, I *believe* that's why it's behaving this way.